# i m customize my site in local xampp but site folder didn't display due to htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i m put my site data folder in local xampp but folder didn't display to my local xampp folder due to htaccess ..... i try but i cann't  display folder and also didn't open my site in local........what can i do .this is my htaccess file what changes is due

```
Options All -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(Admin) - [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&one=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&one=$3&two=$4 [NC,QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype

  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>

<files *.html>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
    </IfModule>
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "modification plus 1 minutes"
ExpiresByType image/png "modification plus 1 minutes"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "modification plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minutes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Displaying folder need option `+Indexes`

Remove `-Indexes` and add :

```
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: i do this "Options +Indexes" but nothing to change anything folder not display and also didn't running to site in local

Comment: @harry Did you remove `Options All -Indexes` ?

Comment: yes remove and replace to Options +Indexes but nothing to change anything

Comment: @harry Check your apache configuration. You have to get `AllowOverride All` to allow `.htaccess` to be used.

Comment: anything else to any changes

Comment: please suggest to me  any changes in "RewriteRule"